# Unzip folder cordova 3.4 ios and android

Tags: android, ios, cordova, zip, unzip

I am trying to unzip a folder in cordova 3.4. But haven't been successful so far. I have seen many tutorials but none of them seems to work for me. Kindly suggest me some plugin or code if you have already done this and if its working.

File is successfully getting saved using http://weblogs.asp.net/soever/cordova-file-transfer-unzip-and-present-adventures, but unzip is not working.

Here is my code, calling for unzip.

```
document.getElementById("btnUnzip").onclick = function() {
    var that = this,
    App = new DownloadApp(),
    fileName = "ft-p.zip",
    folderName = "content";
    console.log("zip button clicked");
    App.unzip(folderName, fileName,
        /*success*/function() { alert("Unzipped and assigned"); },
        /*fail*/function(error) { alert("Unzip failed: " + error.code); }
    );
};
```

Thanks.

Comment: For me using the code from http://weblogs.asp.net/soever/cordova-file-transfer-unzip-and-present-adventures works. But if I try that code with my own zip file it doesn't unzip. I always get result == -1.

Comment: @Update: Now I got it to work. My problem was serverside. The zip File was not correctly delivered. The sample code from http://weblogs.asp.net/soever/cordova-file-transfer-unzip-and-present-adventures definitely works!

Comment: small note for someone stumbling upon this issue. I've faced issues when zipping a file using windows or winrar. 7-zip has given me the best results. Not all zip formats are supported.